# How to use the H5LTget_attribute_string function?

Tags: c, hdf5

I have asked this on the [HDF Forum here](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/question-on-how-to-use-h5ltget-attribute-string/7639) but haven't received an answer (yet). So I thought I try my luck here.

I have created a small test file in Python (h5py) and want to use the `H5LTget_attribute_string` function to read an attribute from it. However, I'm not sure how to use this function.

My test file looks like this.

```
HDF5 "attr.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "my_dataset" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I64LE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 12 ) / ( 12 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "string_attr" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
         DATA {
         (0): "this is a string"
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```

Looking at the [documentation of H5LT_GET_ATTRIBUTE](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/H5LT_GET_ATTRIBUTE)  it seems to me that I need to allocate a buffer and pass the address of the buffer as the last parameter, after which the H5LT_GET_ATTRIBUTE function would fill the buffer. My first attempt was therefore this.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hdf5.h"
#include "hdf5_hl.h"

int main()
{
    herr_t  status;

    hid_t file_id = H5Fopen("attr.h5", H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT);
    assert(file_id >= 0);
    
    char string[1024];  // assume buffer is large enough;
    
    fprintf(stderr, "string : %s\n", string);
    fprintf(stderr, "pointer: %p\n", string);

    fprintf(stderr, "---- reading attribute ----\n");
    status = H5LTget_attribute_string(file_id, "my_dataset", 
                                      "string_attr", string);
    assert(status >= 0);
    
    fprintf(stderr, "string : %s\n", string);
    fprintf(stderr, "pointer: %p\n", string);
    
    status = H5Fclose(file_id);
    assert(status >= 0);
}
```

However this didn't work as expected, see the output below.

```
string : 
pointer: 0x7ffe3f7ec770
---- reading attribute ----
string : @B�k2V
pointer: 0x7ffe3f7ec770
```

After some googling and experimenting I found out that the last parameter should be the address of the buffer. Then the H5LT_GET_ATTRIBUTE function will make the buffer point to the actual attribute value. The following function compiled with a warning but it gave the correct output.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hdf5.h"
#include "hdf5_hl.h"

int main()
{
    herr_t  status;

    hid_t file_id = H5Fopen("attr.h5", H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT);
    assert(file_id >= 0);
    
    char* string = NULL;
    
    fprintf(stderr, "string : %s\n", string);
    fprintf(stderr, "pointer: %p\n", string);

    fprintf(stderr, "---- reading attribute ----\n");
    status = H5LTget_attribute_string(file_id, "my_dataset", 
                                      "string_attr", &string);
    assert(status >= 0);
    
    fprintf(stderr, "string : %s\n", string);
    fprintf(stderr, "pointer: %p\n", string);
    
    status = H5Fclose(file_id);
    assert(status >= 0);
}
```

Output

```
string : (null)
pointer: (nil)
---- reading attribute ----
string : this is a string
pointer: 0x559e9e3d1240
```

Now I am perfectly happy to use it like this, and I can cast to  `**char` to get rid of the warning, but I would like to be sure that this is the expected behavior. Ideally the documentation should be updated.

So my questions are:

1. Is the second example correct?
2. How long is the data in the `string` buffer valid? That is, when is the memory released by the HDF lib? (E.g. when the file is closed)
3. Should I use `strcpy` to copy the string data before using it?

Comment: In the bounty I asked for an "answer from a reputable source" but any help is appreciated and, as long as the answer convinces me, will receive the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pointed](http://hdf-forum.184993.n3.nabble.com/String-attribute-with-HDF5-Lite-td4028022.html#none) by Scot Breitenfeld (from the HDF group):

> If you are reading a variable length string with H5LTget_attribute_string (H5T_VARIABLE) then you don’t need to allocate the string, just pass in a pointer and the library will handle the allocations. If you are reading a fixed length string then you need to allocate a string that is “large enough”.

So, (1) your second approach seems ok to me.

As for (2) and (3), I would bet you are responsible for freeing the buffer, so no need to copy it. However, to be sure, you can use a debugger to check if the library is accessing the buffer or, even better, use `valgrind` to find memory leaks (when you try not to `free` the buffer).

Comment: Thanks for this quote and good idea to use valgrind..

Answer (score 1):

I don't do HDF5, but I do enough C to provide you some answers with a very high percentage of being what you look for.

1. **Is the second example correct?**

yes it is. first because it returns the right and expected result, second
because any library that will fill a string (aka: `char *`) will need you to provide the address of a pointer (aka: `char **`).

2. **How long is the data in the `string` buffer valid?**

It is valid for as long as your program runs. This memory has been allocated for you with the right size, so it is valid for the entire lifetime of your program **but** it is now your responsibility to free it.
If you need more details on that please respond/comment to that message saying so and we'll help you.

3. **Should I use `strcpy` to copy the string data before using it?**

No you don't the memory has been alocated for you, you can keep it as is :-)

---

Next step that I advise you to do:

- Now that you found the issue in their doc you should contact them and tell them.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. About 1: I know that I should provide a `** char` but the documentation and compiler tell me the function expects a `* char`. Hence my confusion.About 2: this indeed is one option but I think it can also be possible that the HDF5 library is responsible for freeing the memory, for instance when the file is closed. In that case i would have to use `strcpy` if I want to use it later.